# Npm start isnt working in react-native

Tags: react-native

hello guys i am developing one react-native app and i implemented some with reference from
http://rationalappdev.com/logging-into-react-native-apps-with-facebook-or-google/

I written the according to the reference but when i click on Login with facebook button it will open inbuilt browser and gives error

my app run on 8081 port
The webpage athttp://localhost:3000/auth/facebook could not be loaded because 
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

here is my package.json from backend folder

backend/package.json

```
{
"name": "backend",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"start": "nodemon node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js"  },
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
"nodemon": "^1.11.0"
 },
"dependencies": {
"cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
"express": "^4.15.3",
"passport": "^0.3.2",
"passport-facebook": "^2.1.1",
"passport-google-oauth20": "^1.0.0"
}
}
```

when i type npm start command it will give

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! backend@1.0.0 start: `node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modul
es/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script 
'node_modules/nodemon/bin/node
mon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the backend package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-
cli/bin/b
abel-node.js server.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs backend
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls backend
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     C:\Users\Abhi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-
 18T12_19_10_3
 94Z-debug.log
```

2017-07-18T12_19_10_394Z-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.2.0
3 info using node@v7.8.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle backend@1.0.0~prestart: backend@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle backend@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle backend@1.0.0~start: backend@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle backend@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle backend@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\react\ephotobook\backend\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Scripts\;C:\Program Files (x86)\;D:\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Abhi\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\
 10 verbose lifecycle backend@1.0.0~start: CWD: D:\react\ephotobook\backend
 11 silly lifecycle backend@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
 11 silly lifecycle   'node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle backend@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle backend@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: backend@1.0.0 start: `node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
15 verbose pkgid backend@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd D:\react\ephotobook\backend
17 error Windows_NT 6.2.9200
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v7.8.0
20 error npm  v4.2.0
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error errno 1
23 error backend@1.0.0 start: `node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js`
23 error Exit status 1
24 error Failed at the backend@1.0.0 start script 'node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js'.
 24 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
 24 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the backend package,
24 error not with npm itself.
24 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
24 error     node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js -- node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node.js server.js
24 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
24 error     npm bugs backend
24 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
24 error     npm owner ls backend
24 error There is likely additional logging output above.
25 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Here is my log file i already write the error log above but i updates the question i am not getting where the thing are wrong

Comment: The last line from the error output: "`Please include the following file with any support request: C:\Users\Abhi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-18T12_19_10_394Z-debug.log`" - can you open that file and paste the content here?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: sir did you get the solution